# Finding all simple paths in a graph using NetworkX

Tags: networkx

I have to analyze some simple graphs with on the order of 20 nodes or so. I need to find all possible paths starting from an arbitrary node in the graph. `all_simple_paths` looked like what I need, except I have to specify an end node. I would like the algorithm to traverse the graph until it finds the end node itself, where end node means it either has no neighbor or it is the last one before an already visited node.

Here is an example:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nodes = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 4], [3, 1], [0, 2]]

# Build the graph. Start with the nodes.
rl_graph = nx.DiGraph()
for link in nodes:
    rl_graph.add_node(link[0])
    rl_graph.add_node(link[1])

# Add the edges.
rl_graph.add_edges_from(nodes)

# Draw.
positions = {}
for idx, node in enumerate(rl_graph.nodes):
    phi = 2 * np.pi / len(rl_graph.nodes) * idx
    positions[node] = [np.cos(phi), np.sin(phi)]
nx.draw(rl_graph, pos=positions)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(rl_graph, positions)    
plt.show()
```

The output I would like to get is all the possible paths starting from a particular node, let's say node 0. The paths I would expect are:

```
0, 1, 2, 3
0, 2, 3, 1
0, 1, 4
0, 2, 3, 1, 4
```

Starting from node 1, for example, I would expect:

```
1, 4
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example (reproducible input and expected output)?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and example. Aren't you missing the path `0, 2, 3, 1, 4` in your output?

Comment: Yes, you are right. that path is also there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom recursive generator:

```py
def find_paths(G, start=0, path=None, seen=None):
    if path is None:
        path = [start]
    if seen is None:
        seen = {start}
    
    # get direct descendants
    desc = nx.descendants_at_distance(G, start, 1)
    if not desc:          # no descendants: STOP
        yield path
    else:
        for n in desc:
            if n in seen: # we already visited this node: STOP
                yield path
            else:
                yield from find_paths(G, n, path+[n], seen.union([n]))
                
list(find_paths(rl_graph, 0))
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 3, 1], [0, 2, 3, 1, 4]]

list(find_paths(rl_graph, 1))
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 4]]
```